# Is it possible to set an EF6 model's primary key value?

Tags: entity-framework-6, primary-key

In Entity Framework 6, when a Model has a [Key] field defined, is it possible to set this value manually, or will the DbContext always set this value itself?

I have done some research, and I cannot quickly find this answer. First I thought that this is possible, tried to set the id in a Create ActionResult, and the id was still added as an increment on the last added DbSet object.

Hence this question.

Thanks

Comment: Add [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] as well, then you have to set the value yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but by default, no?

Comment: by "default", key its set to [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)], which creates IDENTITY COLUMN for table in database. Only way to be able to set the key value by yourself is to change the datatype of key from "int" to "guid" or  "string"

Comment: You could set identity insert on. http://blog.robertobonini.com/2014/10/09/entity-framework-with-identity-insert/